# Change the value of a selection based on another attribute

Tags: jquery

OK so I'm populating a selectbox with a JSON which looks something like this:

```
Object{
"data":
[{"filter":"en","id":"2","label":"English"},
{"filter":"no","id":"3","label":"Norwegian"},
{"filter":"nl","id":"4","label":"Dutch"}]
}
```

Currently if I do `jQuery("#mySelect").val()` I get the value of "id" for the selected option and if I use the `.text()` or `.html()` I get the value of the selected label.
What I want to do is change the selected option based on the value of "filter", so for example I want to check if the option that is selected has the filter "no" and if it doesn't I want to select the option which does.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you put your code in a jsFiddle?

Comment: whats a selectbox ? can you include your HTML and other jQuery ?

Comment: Which option should it pick if the current selection has `filter = no`? the next? the previous?

Comment: @Jack I think my choice of words was poor: so for example if the filter for the current selection is "en" i want to change the selected option the the one which has filter="no". If the filter is already "no" i will leave it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data attributes for your porpose:

html

```
<select>
    <option data-filter="en" value="1">English</option>
    <option data-filter="no" value="2">Norwegian</option>
</select>​
```

js

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).find('option:selected').data('filter');
    alert(id);
});​
```

In case if you will create select dynamically you can set data attributes like: `$('option').data('filter', 'no');`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kzHfF/

P.S. You can put as mutch data attributes as you need.

Comment: A related question: If you want to change the selected option based on value you can do something like $('select').val('2') (as far as i know). Can something like this be done with data? like $('select').data('2') and the selected option would now be the one with data-filter 2?

Comment: Only with the trick: `$("select").val($("select option[data-filter=no]").val());`

Answer (score 1):

Add a new attribute to each option which contains the filter value

```
<select>
    <option filter="en" value="2">English</option>
    <option filter="no" value="3">Norwegian</option>
    <option filter="n1" value="4">Dutch</option>
</select>
```

You will get the selected option with $('select option:selected') and get value of the filter attribute from it.

```
$('select').change(function(){
    console.log($('select option:selected').attr('filter'));
});
```